# What would be a method for creating a number counter in Android?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want to create a scrolling counter that rises at a rate I give it for an Android app, I feel like there is no Android widget that does this well in the SDK and I wanted some idea how this should be accomplished, or even better an open source project around this idea.

Picture example:
[image: Scrolling Counter]

Comment: +1 I am also interested in this kind of widget.

Comment: So you would want it to have fluid animation, blurring, and showing half-numbers, just like in your picture example?

Comment: That would be best case, though I am learning some of this stuff so I would accept anything more basic

Comment: Currently I use a TextView that just updates every 300ms

Comment: Also if I end up figuring this out and making it really easy to work with I will end up making in an open source project, maybe as a really easy to use UI widget

Comment: I know sense's clock app has a similar counter.

Answer (score 5):

This might not be a perfect answer, but at least a starting point. Discounting the animation and general fanciness, you can get most of the way there just by decorating a TextView with some fancy XML. I'll share what I did a few years ago to make a similar-looking screen area for a tip calculator:

Here's the XML. Each single digit is one TextView so you can change them individually. I'm showing two here but obviously there were 5 for the screenshot below.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="60dip" 
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:textSize="64sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="60dip" 
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:textSize="64sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

And the "drawable/gradient" I created as a separate drawable file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#fbbb"
/>
<solid android:color="#600000"/>
<layout_margin android:layout_margin="1dip"/>
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:centerColor="#6D6D6D"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:angle="270"
/>
```

Here's the final result (inside a linearlayout):

[image: Number Counter]

Comment: This is amazing. On top of seeing if I can animate changes to the text view it might be perfect for my needs.

Comment: Glad to hear it. In my implementation the user could press on either the top or bottom portion of each TextView to change the number up or down, so I didn't need animations. If you do need them, I'm not sure if TextView will still be the way to go.

Comment: I am animating a counter rising at a rate that the user would effect, but this is a really good start. The animation is need because it looks so much cleaner then just a refresh of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to raggedToad's answer: You can use the `ViewAnimator` class to add animations to your counter. Its easy to use. You can extend it, add all the digit textviews in `onCreate()`. Implement a method `increment` that handles the increment operation. Just call `showNext` to flip to the next view.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Now I might go try that out on my old-school counter! :)

Comment: So could I make an strip of numbers in an image, only show a portion of the image on screen, and animate the portion show moving then repeat the image when it reaches the end?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this particular counter in your screenshot has some short animations (about 5 or 10 frames) for each transition from one number to the next. Maybe there are also some more for showing rapid transitions without actually stopping at the particular number with more blurring.

So the main task would be creating the graphics. Then it's just a matter of displaying the right frame at the right time.

Comment: This is a great start but I am not familiar at all in working with graphics or animations.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open source project that does the exact thing you are trying to do.
Check: http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: This looks pretty good, I would not be using it as a picker but I should look into making this feet my needs